# Dual space and functionals 2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I consider $ A=\{x^* \in X^* : x^*(x)=0 \} $

$X$ is an abitrary set with its dual space $X^*$.

Why can I say for example, that $x^* \in \mathbb{R^n}$

I thougt, $x^*$ is a functional,  such that $$x^* :  \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$$
Didn' t it have to be $$x^* \in \mathbb{R^n}^*$$

Comment: Maybe because $\Bbb R^{n\ast}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$? What is exactly the question? I see no relation between the first two sentences and the rest.

Comment: The question is: Why can I substitute $X^*$ with $\mathbb{R^n} $  in A.

Comment: Because for finite-dimensional $X$, $X^\ast \simeq X$, so that applies to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: But didnt I have to write$ \mathbb{R^n}^*$